# Why does highcharts not accept an array for second y axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a multi series line graph with two y-Axis using highcharts. The data is being plotted from a CSV on a server. The problem i have is when it comes to plotting more than one series. I can succesfully load all the csv data into arrays. When i try plot the second axis nothing shows up. Am i missing something here?

Here is the html code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    
    
    


    $.get('employeeData.csv', function(data) {

    var lines = data.split('\n');
    console.log(lines);  

        
    var timeData=[];
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
        if(lineNo > 0)
            {
                timeData[lineNo-1] = lineContent.split(',')[0];    
            }
    });


    var weightData=[];
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
        if(lineNo > 0)
            {
                weightData[lineNo-1] = lineContent.split(',')[1];    
            }
    });


    var valueData=[];
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
        if(lineNo > 0)
            {
                valueData[lineNo-1] = parseFloat(lineContent.substring(lineContent.lastIndexOf(",")+1) );
            }
    });

console.log(timeData);
console.log(weightData);
console.log(valueData);




Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },



    title: {
        text: 'employee Data'
    },



    subtitle: {
        text: 'firmA'
    },



    xAxis: {
        categories: timeData,
        crosshair: false
    },


    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}(g)',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Weight',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'secondary axis',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} zCount',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        ////////Notice: importance option
        opposite: true //This option will set position of this axis to the right sie
    }],





    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>Time:</b> {point.x}<br/>',
        pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}:</b> {point.y}<br/>'
    },


    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.01,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },


    series: [{
        name: 'Weight',
        data: weightData

    }, {
        name: 'value',
        data: valueData,
       yAxis: 1
    }]
});

});


</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      


</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

here is the csv

```html
Time,Weight,value
2020/08/18 18h25,29719,59
2020/08/18 18h26,29720,62
2020/08/18 18h27,29759,62
2020/08/18 18h28,29790,63
2020/08/18 18h29,29720,64
2020/08/18 18h30,29721,65
2020/08/18 18h31,29760,70
2020/08/18 18h32,29791,89
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who has had a similar issue, my problem was that i was not parsing the value read from the CSV file to a float. the values were being read as text so to fix this i edited this and added parseFloat();

```js
var weightData=[];
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
        if(lineNo > 0)
            {
                weightData[lineNo-1] = parseFloat(lineContent.split(',')[1]);    
            }
    });
```